# WP REST API Create media return Timeout Gateway in response, but media created

Tags: media, api

Have a problem with REST API for creating media

Trying post image to WordPress and got the good result – media created and Postman got response with id of the new image.

But when I run request from my application I got next result:

1. media created
2. very long time waiting for the response and then got Gateway timeout

```js
create_media(filePath, fileName, fileOption, wp);

function retrieveImageBuffer(url){
        return axios
        .get(url, {
            responseType: "arraybuffer"
        })
        .then(response => Buffer.from(response.data, "binary"))
        .catch(function(err){
            console.error(err);
        });
    }

async function create_media(url, fileName, fileOption, wp){
        let buffer = await retrieveImageBuffer(url);
        try {
            let result = await wp
                .media()
                .file(buffer,fileName)
                .create(fileOption)
                .catch(function(err){
                    console.error(err.body);
                });

            console.log(result);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        }
    }
```

I need id from response for added futured image to the post

When I use REST API from my application to creating a post all work well.

UPDATE 2

And try WP REST API

```js
var url = base_link + '/wp-json/wp/v2/media';
var headers = {
    "Authorization" : base_auth,
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Content-Disposition": 'attachment; filename="'+fileName+'"'
}
var requ = request.post({url:url,headers:headers,method:'POST'}, 
    function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {    
        if (err) {
            return console.error('upload failed:', err);
        }
        console.log(body);
})
var form = requ.form();
form.append('file', fs.createReadStream('file_uploader/'+fileName));
form.append('title', img_title);
form.append('alt_text', alt_text);
form.append('post', post_id);
```

same result

Comment: I notice there is no code to debug in your question, can edit your question using the edit link to include it? it is not possible to answer this question without it

Comment: @TomJNowell added code